# Columns decimalLatitude and decimalLongitud not recognized while creating a layer from a csv file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv

I'm using QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour to create a layer from a csv file. When I try to define the geometry and assign the x y coordinates sources, I'd expect QGIS to recognize the decimalLongitud and decimalLatitud columns, but instead the field is:

gbifID;abstract;accessRights;accrualMethod;accrualPeriodicity;accrualPolicy;alternative;audience;available;bibliographicCitation;conformsTo;contributor;coverage;created;creator;date;dateAccepted;dateC

for both x and y coordinates ...

what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the top few lines of tje file?

Comment: Oh! Thanks for your interest! I just solved the problem. It was just about choosing semicolon as delimiter; so I guess I'll delete the question for us all to forget the matter, right? Thanks again.

Comment: Esther if it can be  reasonably expected to help someone else with a similar difficulty in the future, it's encouraged tp post your own solution and accept the answer. (deleting is fine too if the Q is too localized)